# Get previous element of a different type with PHP Simple Html Dom?

Tags: php, dom, screen-scraping, scrape

Hoping this is possible with Simple Html Dom, I'm scraping a page that looks like this:

```
<h5>this is title 1</h5>
<img>
<img>
<img>

<h5>this is title 2</h5>
<img>
<img>

<h5>this is title 3</h5>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
```

etc...

I'm trying to get it to look something like:

```
<h5>this is title 1</h5>
<img>
<h5>this is title 1</h5>
<img>
<h5>this is title 1</h5>
<img>


<h5>this is title 2</h5>
<img>
<h5>this is title 2</h5>
<img>
```

Which means for each IMG I need to find and grab the first previous H5, I think.  There's no parent divs or any structure to make it any easier, it's pretty much how I described it.

The code I'm using looks something like this (simplified):

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $image){

//do stuff to the img

$title = $html->find('h5')->prev_sibling();


echo $title; echo $image;}
```

Everything I've tried with prev_sibling gets me a "Fatal error: Call to a member function prev_sibling() on a non-object" and I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible with PHP Simple HTML Dom.  I hope so, all the other scrapers I've tried were making me pull my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want to select all `h5` elements, as well as all the `img` elements. Then, you loop through them, and check their type. If it's an `h5` element, you update your `$title` variable but don't `echo` anything. If it's an `img`, you simply echo the `$title` before the image. No need to go hunting for the `h5` now since you've already cached it.

Here's an example:

```
foreach ( $html->find('h5, img') as $el )
{
    if ( $el->tag == 'h5' )
    {
        $title = $el->plaintext;
        continue;
    }

    echo "<h5>$title</h5>";
    echo $el->outertext;
}
```

Comment: This pretty much did it, thanks!  Now I have to figure out how to get the 'alt' from the image but that shouldn't be too hard, I hope.

Comment: @jthomasbailey - Use this: `if ( isset($el->alt) ) $alt = $el->alt;`

Comment: Why do u steal other people's answer? Is that how you get ur rep?

Comment: @Churk - I'm sorry you feel that I **stole** your answer. If you look at the timestamp, you'll see that I posted my answer about 3 minutes after you. It took me much longer than that to set up a test environment, copy the OP's code, skim through the [Simple HTML Dom documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) & then test it. The fact that you posted similar code to mine 2-3 minutes before me is just unfortunate. I will however - for harmony's sake - upvote your answer. Again, I'm sorry for the way you feel, but I did not **steal** anything from you.

Comment: @JosephSilber sorry for the backlash, just that this happened two me a few times within that last few days, and it wasn't by few minutes but more than 1/2 hrs +, and most of them are from high rep people, 5K+.

Comment: Not sure why I tried Joseph's answer before Churk's, I guess it seemed easier to just drop into my code but huge thanks to both of you, I was trying to figure this out literally all night the night before and within 10 minutes of posting on here I had an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Because you are not loading the entire page as a dom, what you essentially have is a list of DOMElement and previous child will be NULL.

Instead of finding previously, what you can essentially do is, have a moving pointer

```
$all = get all elements,
$title = null;
foreach ($all as $e) {
  if ($e == "h5") {
    $title = $e;
    continue;
  }
  echo $title . $e;
}
```

There are some sedo code, but you'll get what I mean.